# Error ORA-30076 when trying to translate from Hana to Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax-error

I'm trying to convert a script from Hana to Oracle and I keep getting the same error on Rule_def.DATEUPD on line 5 which says that the field is not valid for the extraction.
Can someone please tell me how to translate that part in Oracle correctly? Thanks!

```
SELECT 
    P2_RULE,
    P2_ORIGIN,
    Rule_def.DATEUPD as P2_DATE,
    substr('0' || extract(hour from Rule_def.DATEUPD),2) 
    || ':' || 
    substr('0' || extract(minute from Rule_def.DATEUPD),2)
    || ':' || 
    substr('0' || extract(second from Rule_def.DATEUPD),2) AS P2_DATETIME,
    Rule_def.USERUPD || ' | ' || DESC_UTENTE as P2_USER
FROM (
    SELECT 
        P2_RULE,
        P2_ORIGIN,
        DATEUPD,
        USERUPD,
        ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by P2_RULE, p2_origin order by DATEUPD desc) as N_row
    FROM AW_PII_P20018_000001
    WHERE dateupd is not null) Rule_def
join UTENTE
ON Rule_def.USERUPD = COD_UTENTE    
WHERE N_ROW = 1
```

I've tried some date's formulas but they don't work

Answer (score 1):

You appear to want to use `TO_CHAR` rather than complex formatting with `SUBSTR`:

```sql
SELECT r.P2_RULE,
       r.P2_ORIGIN,
       r.DATEUPD as P2_DATE,
       TO_CHAR(r.DATEUPD, 'HH24:MI:SS') AS P2_DATETIME,
       r.USERUPD || ' | ' || u.DESC_UTENTE as P2_USER
FROM   ( SELECT P2_RULE,
                P2_ORIGIN,
                DATEUPD,
                USERUPD,
                ROW_NUMBER() over (
                  partition by P2_RULE, p2_origin order by DATEUPD desc
                ) as N_row
         FROM   AW_PII_P20018_000001
         WHERE dateupd is not null
       ) r
       join UTENTE u
       ON r.USERUPD = u.COD_UTENTE    
WHERE  r.N_ROW = 1
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE AW_PII_P20018_000001 (P2_RULE, P2_ORIGIN, DATEUPD, USERUPD) AS
SELECT 1, 2, SYSDATE, 3 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE utente (desc_utente, cod_utente) AS
SELECT 'A', 3 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| P2_RULE | P2_ORIGIN | P2_DATE | P2_DATETIME | P2_USER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2023-06-05 14:39:03 | 14:39:03 | 3 | A |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/lclF2RtD)

Answer (score 0):

From the oracle docs,

> If HOUR, MINUTE, or SECOND is requested, then expr must evaluate to an
> expression of data type TIMESTAMP, TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE, TIMESTAMP
> WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE, or INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND. DATE is not valid
> here, because Oracle Database treats it as ANSI DATE data type, which
> has no time fields.

So you need to convert the DATE field's type to TIMESTAMP with:

```
extract(hour from cast(Rule_def.DATEUPD as timestamp))
```

etc. for minute and second also